How to enable debug false in Laravel 11
I have a website built with laravel 11 and it is live, I want to hide the server errors such as { "status": "exception", "message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Application].", "line": 637, "file": "path_to/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php" }
I edited .env file with APP_DEBUG=false and APP_ENV=production but I got this errors also, I tried to add a blade named 500.blade.php under errors folder with custom message but nothing was changed
But for 404 error I succeed to have a custom page : I created a 404 blade file and I added a route :
 Route::fallback(function () {
        return view('errors.404');
    });

can someone helps to hide the server errors please!

Can you verify that the app correctly read the values of .env? What's the output of env('APP_DEBUG') and env('APP_ENV')? How does your config/app.php look like? Is your configuration cached? As it stands there is too little information to provide an answer

@tobifasc env(APP_DEBUG) return null but when I tried with dd(config('app.debug'));  it return false  same thing for APP_ENV
my config/app.php file is correct :  'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),   'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false), 

Now I'm unsure as to how laravel intended this exception to look when debug is disabled? Isn't this already the intended output?

@MAHAOUEGHLANI , Basically you want to implement exception handling with a 500.blade.php file,right ? Tell us which version of laravel you are using?

@Subha Yes, I mentionned that I use Laravel 11

@tobifasc, if debug is disabled normaly it gives me a white page with "500 error server"  message

Since you are getting 500 error server when debug is disabled, what else you want to achieve ,please clarify.

@Subha I replied to tobifasc and I said NORMALY it gives 500 error server, but NO

Your env might be using an old value if you use artisan config:cache. You can probably try php artisan config:clear

Check the .env file there APP_DEBUG variable:
Replace that with true to false: APP_DEBUG=false
After that run this command on terminal: php artisan config:clear

Have you tried this?

You can try to override the default error handler behavior.
Take a look at the file bootstrap\app.php. You can try something like this:
->withExceptions(function (Throwable|Exceptions $exceptions) {
  
  $exceptions->renderable(function (Throwable|Exceptions $e, $request) {

    return response()->view('your_default_error_view_here');

  });

})->create();

The code above will render a view for every request (Sure you can improve this code as you want)
